# mysql select query search one word in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

Help is required.
i am preparing a search form. need help in select query
is it possible that i can search "building" word in all columns of my table
following is the query i've tried.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property WHERE posthead,requestto,ptype,requestby,owner,bed,bath,price,sqft,descp = '".$search."'");
$result = (mysql_fetch_array($sql));

echo "Post Head : ". $result['posthead']."<br />";
echo "Request To : ". $result['requestto']."<br />";
echo "Type : ". $result['ptype']."<br />";
echo "Request By : ". $result['requestby']."<br />";
echo "Owner : ". $result['owner']."<br />";
echo "Bed : ". $result['bed']."<br />";
echo "Bath : ". $result['bath']."<br />";
echo "Price : ". $result['price']."<br />";
echo "Sq ft. : ". $result['sqft']."<br />";
echo "Description : ". $result['descp']."<br />";
```

Comment: Yes, read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SELECT * FROM property WHERE posthead = $search OR requestto = $search ...` etc

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property WHERE posthead = '".$search."' OR requestto= '".$search."' OR ptype= '".$search."' OR requestby = '".$search."' OR owner= '".$search."' OR bed = '".$search."' OR bath= '".$search."' OR price= '".$search."' OR sqft,descp = '".$search."'");
```

and change `$result = (mysql_fetch_array($sql));` to `$result = (mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));`

**NOTE :**

1. your query is vulnerable to sql injection
2. mysql_* functions are deprecated use mysqli_* or PDO

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS:**

Better is to use **`"CONCAT"`** for the columns:

> $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property WHERE
>   CONCAT(posthead,requestto,ptype,requestby,owner,bed,bath,price,sqft,descp)
>   LIKE "%.$search."%'");

**`OR`** will work but **`CONCAT`** can reduce query size.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a searching form you might want to be able to find records by partial match and not exact word. In order to do that you can use `LIKE`

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM property 
WHERE posthead  LIKE '%$search%' OR
      requestto LIKE '%$search%' OR
      ptype     LIKE '%$search%' OR
      requestby LIKE '%$search%' OR
      owner     LIKE '%$search%' OR
      bed       LIKE '%$search%' OR
      bath      LIKE '%$search%' OR
      price     LIKE '%$search%' OR
      sqft      LIKE '%$search%' OR
      descp     LIKE '%$search%'";

$sql = mysql_query($q);
```